# how to use parameters from bitbucket server hook call to jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

Bitbucket server(stash) webhook plugin (https://github.com/Nerdwin15/stash-jenkins-postreceive-webhook/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nerdwin15/stash/webhook/Notifier.java)  triggers a jenkins job through web hook with a specific commit in the call. Now jenkins job is triggered but only polls the repo, while I want the specific commit sha1 to be built that was sent in that call. How to get that commit sha1 string from the call that was received by jenkins?

The reason I'm asking is that jenkins jobs and pipelines when for example you make 10 commits in parallel tend to stack the commits into one build which is what I want to avoid here.

env.GIT_COMMIT works only after the git scm polling within the job which is not the thing I'm looking for here. I'm using mainly jenkinsfiles and jenkins pipelines
To put it simple I want to pass that sha1 value from the bitbucket webhook into my pipeline. For example

```
node {
   checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: MY_DESIRED_SHA1]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: []])
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using pipeline scripts, I could not get the commit notify to trigger the job this way, it seemed to be a limitation of how the git plugin worked. Tested on

```
Jenkins (2.19.1)
Git Plugin(3.0.0)
```

I had to change the way that the job was triggered to using buildwithParameter webhook. This is not available with the [Bitbucket server(stash) webhook plugin](https://github.com/Nerdwin15/stash-jenkins-postreceive-webhook/blob/master/src/main/java/com/nerdwin15/stash/webhook/Notifier.java)

I then used the following bitbucket server plugin
[Pull Request Notifier for bitbucket](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/pull-request-notifier-for-bitbucket)

Configured for pull request building but it can build on change once a pull request is created.

A comprehensive description of how i achieve this is available [here](https://dengelonsoftware.blogspot.co.uk/2017/01/jenkins-pull-request-and-pipeline.html)

Comment: What do you think about triggering parametrized build/pipeline using .git/hooks/post-receive curl http://yourserver/jenkins/git/notifyCommit?url=<URL of the Git repository>  with the sha1 parameter?

Comment: @koller23 the git plugin will look for jobs which clone from the url of the commitnotify, only for jobs configured using the git plugin and polling, pipeline jobs are not as far as i know configured this way.